# A combinatorial way to understand $\sum \log^2 n $

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, computer-science

Stirling's formula has many derivations using the factorial function:

$$ \log N! = \sum_{n=1}^N \log n = 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n \bigg( \log m - \log (m-1) \bigg)
 = 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n - \log  \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{m} \bigg) $$

Then we can use the identity $\log (1+x) \approx  x$ to obtain a Harmonic series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n - \log  \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{m} \bigg) \approx 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} 
= \sum_{m=1}^N \frac{N-m}{m} 
= \sum_{m=1}^N \left( N \cdot \frac{1}{m}- 1 \right)\approx N \log N - N$$

---

What can we say about the sum of squares of logarithms?  Since $\log^2 n$ has no special addition or multiplication rules the combinatoris is harder to decipher.

Both asymptotics can be found quickly using integration by parts or other great calculus tricks.  Adding $\log^2 n $ together tends to be appears more in number theory and I wondered also counted something, as $N!$ does.

Here is my contrived derivation:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \log^2 n = 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n \bigg( \log^2 m - \log^2 (m-1) \bigg)
$$

The terms in parentheses can be estimated using the mean value theorem:

$$  \log^2 m - \log^2 (m-1) 
= \log^2 m - \left( \log m - \log (1 - \frac{1}{m})\right)^2 
\approx  \tfrac{2}{m} \log m$$

Then can insert back into the formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^n\tfrac{1}{m} \log m
=  \sum_{m=1}^N\frac{N-m}{m} \;\log m
=  N \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^N\frac{1}{m} \;\log m}_{}
-   \sum_{m=1}^N\log m
$$

What is the combinatorial meaning of $\prod_{m=1}^N m^{1/m}$ ?  Is there any way to  put this quantity in analogy with $N! $ ?

Comment: candidate: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html